# Parent domain cookies for Single Sign on

Tags: authentication, cookies, oauth, single-sign-on

Typically Single Sign On is implemented with existing protocols like SAML or OAuth. If all the sites belongs to the same parent domain such as `a.example.com` and `b.example.com`, we can also set a session cookie for `example.com` domain for SSO. I understand that typical SSO solutions can cross domains, but in terms of security (instead of functionality), how is this pure-cookies naive solution compared to those protocols like OAuth or SAML? Which one is safer, and why?